# could not Convert legacy permission algorithm to 5 while migrating from liferay 5.2.3 to 6.0.6 tomcat with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, liferay, database-migration

```
     Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/convert_process, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, 
     payload=com.liferay.portal.convert.ConvertPermissionAlgorithm, values=null} 

     com.liferay.portal.convert.ConvertException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou pr+¿s de -½ XSS -+  Position-á: 429       
     at com.liferay.portal.convert.ConvertProcess.convert(ConvertProcess.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.convert.messaging.ConvertProcessMessageListener.doReceive(ConvertProcessMessageListener.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.convert.messaging.ConvertProcessMessageListener.receive(ConvertProcessMessageListener.java:32)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:63)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.SerialDestination$1.run(SerialDestination.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
```

After this exception the system falls and shows this message:

The system is currently undergoing maintenance. Please try again later.
Ø«, 18 Ù†ÙˆÙ 2014 10:00:37 +0000 Executing com.liferay.portal.convert.ConvertPermissionAlgorithm

Comment: Looks like an erreur de syntaxe: `ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou pr+¿s` Could be encoding. Please check the postgres log for the actual offending statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved :
I followed this link

http://vetal-liferay.blogspot.com/2014/01/liferay-migration-form-523-to-62.html

but instead of changing the permission.user.check.algorithm in liferay 6.0.6 i have changed it in 6.1.1.